# What are three ways for a developer to execute tests in an Org?

Tags: apex, unit-test, process-builder, visual-workflow

What are three ways for a developer to execute tests in an Org from the following options ?

1. Bulk API
2. Tooling API
3. Setup Menu
4. SalesforceDX
5. MetaData API

In my opinion, it should be Tooling API, Setup Menu, and MetaData API. Because -

**Setup Menu -** By browsing to setup->Apex Test Execution 
**Tooling API -** You can also run tests using the Tooling REST API. Use the /runTestsAsynchronous/ and /runTestsSynchronous/ endpoints to run tests asynchronously or synchronously. 
**MetaData API -** Not sure about it. But found a link - [Unit tests executed via metadata API failing on call to system.test.startTest](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55887/unit-tests-executed-via-metadata-api-failing-on-call-to-system-test-starttest)

Reference link- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm

**Also how can a developer check the test coverage of active Process Builder and Flows before deploying them in a change set?**

Please suggest your opinion with references and steps to produce. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Setup Menu, Tooling API and SalesforceDX.

The link you provided mentions that as well (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm)

> Running Tests Through the Salesforce User Interface

> Running Tests Using the Salesforce Extensions for Visual Studio Code

VS Code uses sfdx.

> Running Tests Using the API - You can also run tests using the Tooling REST API.

Regarding coverage, have a look at the following link:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_test_coverage.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can execute Test classes in apex by inserting a record of [ApexTestQueueItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apextestqueueitem.htm)

```
Insert new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId=[SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name='OportunityTriggerHandlerTest'][0].Id);
```

And then check results as

```
[SELECT Id,ApexClass.Name,ApexTestRunResult.ClassesCompleted FROM ApexTestResult];
```

Regarding testing flows. You just run normal apex classses and then see coverage by querrying [FlowTestCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowtestcoverage.htm) and [FlowElementTestCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowelementtestcoverage.htm)